# How to create a Java Text-Based Hangman Game and other issues

Tags: java

I am creating a Hangman Game in Java and it almost works perfectly. So I have two problems. The first being that:

When the user inputs a letter and the word has repeated letters, how can I make it print both instances of the letter.

- I have created a while loop however this loop does not output the Modified word until after the next go. If that makes sense?
  The second problem:
  I need to be able to prevent the user from entering the same letter twice
- I have attempted Lists and arrays and hash sets. All sorts but none seem to work.

My code is below:

There may be other threads with same questions but none seem to help as I cannot implement it into this person's code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Hangman{

public static void main(String []args){
Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] CollectionOfWords = {"","gravity","banana","gate","processor","momentum","earth","star","light","television","pan","cupboard"};

    int radmNumber = (int) Math.ceil (Math.random() * CollectionOfWords.length);
    int counter = 10;
    String radmWord = CollectionOfWords[radmNumber];

    char[] genRadmLetter = radmWord.toCharArray();
    char[] genRadmLetter2 = radmWord.toCharArray();
    for (int x = 0; x<genRadmLetter.length; x++){
        genRadmLetter[x]='?';
    }

    System.out.println(String.valueOf(genRadmLetter));
    System.out.println("Hello. Guess a letter.");
    char guessedLetter = Input.next().charAt(0);
    int RW = radmWord.indexOf(guessedLetter);

    if (RW >= 0 ){

    genRadmLetter[RW] = guessedLetter;
    System.out.println(genRadmLetter);

    }

    if (RW == -1){
        System.out.println("Wrong letter, try again.");
        counter = counter - 1; 
        System.out.println("Lives left: " + counter);
    }

    while (counter != 0) {

        System.out.println("Guess a letter.");
        guessedLetter = Input.next().charAt(0);
        RW = radmWord.indexOf(guessedLetter);


        if (RW >= 0 ){

        genRadmLetter[RW] = guessedLetter;
        System.out.println(genRadmLetter);
    }

        if (RW == -1){
            System.out.println("Wrong letter, try again.");
            counter = counter - 1; 
            System.out.println("Lives left: " + counter);
    } else {
            System.out.println(genRadmLetter);
            while (RW >= 0 ){
                genRadmLetter[RW] = guessedLetter;
                RW = radmWord.indexOf(guessedLetter, RW+1); 
            }
    }

        boolean result = Arrays.equals(genRadmLetter, genRadmLetter2);
        if (result == true){
            break;
        }

        if (counter == 0){
            break;
        }

    }

    if (counter == 0){
        System.out.println("You lose. The word was: " + radmWord);
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("Well done, you have guessed the word.");
        System.out.println("Your final score is: " + counter);
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using...

```
int RW = radmWord.indexOf(guessedLetter);
```

To determine if the entered value matches a character, which will only return the first index, you should, instead, use a loop of some kind to check every character

```
boolean found = false;
for (int rw = 0; rw < genRadmLetter2.length; rw++) {

    if (genRadmLetter2[rw] == guessedLetter) {

        genRadmLetter[rw] = guessedLetter;
        found = true;

    }

}
```

Now, because you're relying on the value of `RW` to determine if a match was found or not, I changed it so that the `boolean` `found` flag can used instead, for example...

```
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("Wrong letter, try again.");
    counter = counter - 1;
    System.out.println("Lives left: " + counter);
}
```

You also have duplicate sets of code, which can be reduced to a single `do-while` loop instead, which will make it easier to read and make changes, for example...

```
do {

    //...

} while (counter != 0);
```

To your second problem, a `Set` of some kind would be the simplest solution...

```
Set<Character> guesses = new HashSet<Character>();
//...
char guessedLetter = Input.next().charAt(0);

if (guesses.contains(guessedLetter)) {

    System.out.println("You've used this guess, guess again");

} else {

    guesses.add(guessedLetter);
```

For example...

And because it's not always easy to translate code snippets ... this is my test code...

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Hangman {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] CollectionOfWords = {"", "gravity", "banana", "gate", "processor", "momentum", "earth", "star", "light", "television", "pan", "cupboard"};

        int radmNumber = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * CollectionOfWords.length);
        int counter = 10;
        String radmWord = "banana"; //CollectionOfWords[radmNumber];

        char[] genRadmLetter = radmWord.toCharArray();
        char[] genRadmLetter2 = radmWord.toCharArray();
        for (int x = 0; x < genRadmLetter.length; x++) {
            genRadmLetter[x] = '?';
        }

        Set<Character> guesses = new HashSet<Character>();
        do {

            System.out.println("Guess a letter.");

            System.out.println(String.valueOf(genRadmLetter));
            System.out.println("Hello. Guess a letter.");
            char guessedLetter = Input.next().charAt(0);

            if (guesses.contains(guessedLetter)) {

                System.out.println("You've used this guess, guess again");

            } else {

                guesses.add(guessedLetter);
                boolean found = false;
                for (int rw = 0; rw < genRadmLetter2.length; rw++) {

                    if (genRadmLetter2[rw] == guessedLetter) {

                        genRadmLetter[rw] = guessedLetter;
                        found = true;

                    }

                }

                if (!found) {
                    System.out.println("Wrong letter, try again.");
                    counter = counter - 1;
                    System.out.println("Lives left: " + counter);
                }

            }

            boolean result = Arrays.equals(genRadmLetter, genRadmLetter2);
            if (result == true) {
                break;
            }

            if (counter == 0) {
                break;
            }

        } while (counter != 0);

        if (counter == 0) {
            System.out.println("You lose. The word was: " + radmWord);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Well done, you have guessed the word.");
            System.out.println("Your final score is: " + counter);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks man! I understood most of it and I realise my mistake when I tried to use the set. You simplified that perfectly. The summary at the end was extremely well put. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Hi, I needed a bit more help. At the end of the program, I'm required to allow the user to input the new set of words for the next game. I have created a loop at the beginning of the main method that will run 3 times. I need to change the Strings in "CollectionOfWords" to Strings that the user chooses. Any idea how to do this? I have tried converting it to a list Array, but it didn't work out as this would result in changing lots of other parts of the program. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with the code:

1. the typical beginners problem of length vs. max element number
2. unnecessary duplicate code
3. a logic issue with the output

#### as for 1.:

you are using this:

```
int radmNumber = (int) Math.ceil (Math.random() * CollectionOfWords.length)
```

if you use

```
int radmNumber = (int) Math.ceil (Math.random() * CollectionOfWords.length-1)
```

you can start the arrey without a empty string and it wont randomly crash

#### on to 2.

you wont need to duplicate the input code if you use this:

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(genRadmLetter));
System.out.print("Hello.");
char guessedLetter;
int RW; 
while (counter != 0)
{
    System.out.println("Guess a letter.");
...
```

#### and finally 3.(your main question)

you do the output before changing it. so this fixes your problem:

```
... 
else
{
  while (RW >= 0)
  {
      genRadmLetter[RW] = guessedLetter;
      RW = radmWord.indexOf(guessedLetter, RW + 1);
  }
  System.out.println(genRadmLetter);
}
```

So simply move the output behind the while.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little helper clas that could help you...

```
static class GuessString {
   private char[] mask;
   private String solution;
   private boolean lastGuessResult;
   GuessString(String word) {
      this.solution = word;
      this.mask=word.toCharArray();
      Arrays.fill(mask, '?');   // Build a mask like: ??????    
   }

    public String guess(char guess) {
        char c = Character.toLowerCase(guess); // case insensitive
        int i = solution.indexOf(c); 
        lastGuessResult = i != -1; // -1 means "not found)
        if (lastGuessResult)
        while (i != -1) { // this will loop till c is replaced everywhere.
            mask[i] = c;
            i = solution.indexOf(c, i+1); 
        }
        return new String(mask); // return the updated mask.
    }
    public boolean lastGuessIsRight() {
        return lastGuessResult;
    }
    public String getCurrent() {
        return new String(mask);
    }
    public boolean isSolved() {
        return getCurrent().equals(solution);
    }
}
```